# canvas.toDataURL() not returning

Tags: screenshot, html2canvas

i'm trying to do this code, but doesn't working:

```
function iframeLoad(iframe) {

  var body = $(iframe).contents().find('body');

  html2canvas(body, {
    onrendered: function( canvas ) {

        alert(canvas.toDataURL());
        //this alert doesn't working


    },
    allowTaint: true,
    taintTest: false,
    logging: true
  });

}
```

If a change the var "body" to body on my page (not iframe), it works:

```
var body = $('body');
```

Thanks :D

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. If it works what is the problem?

Comment: it's not working with this:   var body = $(iframe).contents().find('body');

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer rather than as an edit to your question